# Weird SNAPTIME$$ value inserted

Tags: oracle, materialized-views

We have created a materialized view log on a table and can see that there is a column automatically created in the MV Log whose name is SNAPTIME$$ and the default value inserted  is "01-01-4000 00:00:00"
We wish to know what is the purpose of this column in relation to the MV Log and why the default value looks like this? When and how this column is used? When and how this value is updated?

Answer (score 1):

`snaptime$$` is used for oracle internal purpose and it is modified when the `MV` is refreshed.

But please note that It is used only when there are `multiple snapshots` for a `single master` is defined.

When a snapshot refreshes the value of the column is set to the time of refresh. so that when it refreshes later it can skip rows that are already refreshed.

Refer to [this documentation](https://avdeo.com/tag/snaptime/) on the same.

Cheers!!